# Close menu once it reaches left end of the window

Tags: titanium, titanium-alloy, appcelerator-mobile

I am implementing a slide menu. Below is my view. $.MenuWrapper is of full width with transparent background and $.menu width is "70%" with white background

```
<Alloy>
   <View id="MenuWrapper">
        <View id="menu" >
          <TableView id="Nodes" />
       </View>
    </View>
</Alloy>
```

Now to close the menu I want to drag $.menu and once it reaches the left end then only it should close the entire menu like many App does. Please help

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are trying to implement a `DrawerMenu` style yeah?

Well, that is not an exactly answer to your question, but I think that you can embrace the flexibility of the Alloy Widgets and the power of Titanium community to reduce your development time focusing in your business logical and not implementing things that someone else already did.

Here is a good `DrawerMenu` widget powered by @FokkeZB

https://github.com/FokkeZB/nl.fokkezb.drawer

You can also check ready-to-use widgets [here](http://gitt.io/)